# Give an example of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and 2d vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal to each other.

Tags: matrices

Give an example of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and 2-dimensional vectors $x$ and
$y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal to each other, but the vectors $Ax$ and
$Ay$ are not orthogonal to each other.

I'm not really getting anywhere in the problem. The dot product of $x$ and $y$ must be $0$, but I'm not sure how to get a $2\times 2$ matrix of $A$ that results in $Ax$ dot $Ay = 0$. Shouldn't it follow that if $x*y = 0$, and $Ax*Ay\neq 0$, then the solution can't exist?

Comment: Orthogonal wrt the standard product?

Comment: @InsideOut The dot product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$, they verify the assumptions. Then take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Can you explain how you find the matrix in the first place? I wasn't really sure how to start this considering my failed assumptions in the beginning.

Comment: I chose two vectors that satisfy the assumption, namely the dot product is zero. In particular I chose a basis. Then I chose another basis that doesn’t satisfy the assumption. The base changing matrix is an example of matrix you are looking for.